# Stream audio mp3 file in chunks from Laravel API to Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, http, audio-streaming

How do I stream an audio file in chunks from Laravel as an API to a client-side Angular web application?

My problem is that when I subscribe to a `httpClient` request, it waits for a whole audio to be downloaded and then plays it. How can I send a request back with like the first 30 seconds of audio data? Can it be done with HTTP Headers like Content-Length or Bytes?